# Two collider in one game object how to distinguish between them when colliding with another?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D game, there is one player with two collider : a box collider 2D on top and a small circle collider 2D bottom. When the player jump on the box he will be ok, but when he collide with the box with his face(box collider 2D) he will die ? How can I do that? I tried the following code , but it not work. Please help me.Thanks!

```
 if (GetComponent<Collider2D>().GetType() == typeof(BoxCollider2D))
 {
 //do something
 }
 if (GetComponent<Collider2D>().GetType() == typeof(CircleCollider2D))
 {
 //do something
 }
```

Comment: Are you checking in the player script? or script attached to other object?

Comment: the script is attached to the player @HamzaHasan

Comment: are you checking it OnCollisionEnter?

Comment: By the way you can make two children of player having each collider (circle and box). And handle them their.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a certain `BoxCollider`, you can use `GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>()` and `GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>()`

However, I am not sure how to take this information and check which one fired the the `OnCollisionEnter`, unless you set one collider to a trigger, and use `OnTriggerEnter` for one, and `OnCollisionEnter` for the other.

What I would recommend is having two child game objects on the player and put both colliders on each game object, and handle each event in their own `OnCollisonEnter`

Comment: I did suggest the same in comment, but no reply :). Confusion still exists that where he is checking this in this manner :)